# Send email via GMail SMTP in REBOL 2

Tags: gmail, rebol, rebol2

I am new to REBOL. People blogging about how great REBOL is used sending an email as an example, similar to this example from the "send" documentation:

```
send luke@rebol.com "Testing REBOL Function Summary"
```

having read how easy and convenient it is to do this, I excitedly tried to send myself a test email via my GMail account.

I looked at the official GMail help for SMTP/POP to get the relevant SMTP/POP server names:
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=en

And here is how far the "send" and "set-net" documentation got me:

```
>> set-net [ myrealusername@gmail.com smtp.gmail.com pop.gmail.com ]
>> send myrealusername@gmail.com "Hello me!"
connecting to: smtp.gmail.com
** Access Error: Cannot connect to smtp.gmail.com
** Where: open-proto
** Near: smtp-port: open [scheme: 'esmtp]
either only
```

On reflection, of course it didn't work; I told REBOL nothing about wanting to use SSL/TLS, the relevant port numbers, or my GMail password.  It must need all of the above to actually send an email.

So how do I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I modified the [protocols](https://github.com/gchiu/Rebol2/tree/master/Protocols) some years ago to work with gmail.  I hope that they still work.

You'll need to run both the prot-ssmtp.r and prot-ssend.r, and you'll need a version of rebol2 which supports ssl.  This is either a free view build, or a paid core build.

```
do https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gchiu/Rebol2/master/Protocols/prot-ssmtp.r
do https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gchiu/Rebol2/master/Protocols/prot-ssend.r
```

Now, you can either set the user and password manually:

```
system/schemes/esmtp/user: "username"
system/schemes/esmtp/pass: "password"
```

or, when the script runs the very first time, you will be asked the values so that they can be set for that rebol instance.  The prot-ssmtp uses port 465 but you can modify that if it's no longer correct.

And then it should be as straight forward after setting **set-net** as:

```
ssend email@someon.com "This is my message"
```

Note that we now have [email](https://github.com/r3n/renclib/wiki/Email---pop3,-smtp,-set-net-and-identities) on [ren-c](http://metaeducation.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) which is the open source fork of rebol3.

Comment: Thanks, but there was no prompt to set user and password when I ran those scripts, nor when I invoked ssend.  How do I manually set the user and password?  (It's not mentioned in the REBOL SMTP doco and I tried something similar to the POP address which also didn't work: ssend username:password@gmail.com "hello me")

Comment: Ok, added code to set the user/pass manually.  I guess I never implemented the ask user for those details.  And parsing out the username won't work in send username:password@gmail.com since the username also contains the "@" character.

Comment: @user310291 you need to ask another question.